# Read rows from a mysql table via java

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I need sample code to read rows of data from a mysql table using java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Standard tutorial from Oracle/Sun](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/gettingstarted.html)

[example with explanation](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/MySQLJava/article.html

Google is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial with sample code: http://www.developer.com/java/data/article.php/3417381/Using-JDBC-with-MySQL-Getting-Started.htm

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using the JDBC API directly, it's error prone (sooner or later you forget to close a conection) and too verbose. There are many nice layers to use on top of JDBC. If you want to write SQL, I think [Spring JDBCTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) is nice. Or better, [Groovy's SQL support](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Database+features) (if you are just bound to 'Java the platform', not 'Java the language').
Then there are object relational mappers (ORM) where you don't need to write SQL. Take a look at [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/) and [JPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API)

Comment: You're forgetting that the company writing database drivers uses JDBC.....